# Starcraft II Patches not Downloading Correctly

Tags: starcraft-2

Ever since I first installed the Free Version(Then later on upgraded to full version) the patches always stopped installing at random percentages and it will stay there. The way I fixed it and finally downloaded it was to continuously opening and closing it quite literally 100+ times. Every time it would download a little further and then stop. It did this again whenever any patches are out and need to updated before I can play.

Is there a solution on this? There are tons of articles on the internet about this but none give a solution that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like their infamous peer 2 peer downloading (i.e. sometimes stopping or slowing down till a specific share ratio is reached). Did you try disabling peer 2 peer downloads?

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue similar to this however it was with the paid US client patching without the free client step.  In my case it was a simple router issue (not forwarding ports etc).

As a work a round: Have you tried [installing the patches manually](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/starcraft-ii-patch-mirror-and-information)?